# Update child class element based on id in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a interface.

```
  export interface DefaultFormList {
  defaultFormItems?: DefaultFormItems[];
  }
```

and

```
export interface DefaultFormItems {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  formXml: string,
  isDefaultFormEnable: boolean;
}
```

I want to update the formXml based on particular id, rest don't need to change.

Below is the code snippet where i try to update the formXml based on formId.

How I can proceed further, below lines are only for reference.

```
  const updatedDefautItems: DefaultFormItems[] = { ...this.state.defaultFormList.defaultFormItems, 
  formXml: updatedFormXmlString };
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the `formXml` base on particular `id` you should add to your code snippet next:

```
const { defaultFormList: { defaultFormItems } } = this.state;

const itemIndexToUpdate: number = defaultFormItems
  .map(item => item.id)
  .indexOf(formId);

const updatedDefaultItems: DefaultFormItems[] = [
  ...defaultFormItems.slice(0, itemIndexToUpdate),
  {
    ...defaultFormItems[itemIndexToUpdate],
    formXml: updatedFormXmlString,
  },
  ...defaultFormItems.slice(itemIndexToUpdate + 1),
]
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error on
{
    ...defaultFormItems[itemIndexToUpdate],
    formXml: updatedFormXmlString,
  },
  ...defaultFormItems.slice(itemIndexToUpdate + 1),
}

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
const { defaultFormList: { defaultFormItems } } = this.state;

const list = [...defaultFormItems];
const item = list.find(i => i.id === formId);
const index = list.findIndex(i => i.id === formId);
if(item){
list.splice(index , 1 , {...item , formXml: updatedFormXmlString,});
}
this.setState({defaultFormList: { defaultFormItems : [...list]}});
```